# SQL Server: Can I have a derived column in a table from columns in that table?

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering if I could have a derived column in my table that I guess is 'automatically' calculated when I insert rows in that table. For example, I'm thinking of a table like this:

```
Object ID | Object Path                                   | File Type
1           /Documents/Subfolder/Subfolder2/FileName.ascx   .ascx
2           /Documents/Subfolder/FileName2.png              .png
```

I don't know if it's possible to make File Type be automatically generated from Object Path, since it's just a substring of the data in Object Path.

Is there a way to do this? Right now I am just creating a stored procedure that returns the File Type but I was wondering if there was a way to have File Type as part of the table and not just in a result set from a `SELECT` query. Thanks.

Comment: You could create a computed column in your table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add computed column, here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products 
(
    ProductID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  , QtyAvailable smallint
  , UnitPrice money
  , InventoryValue AS QtyAvailable * UnitPrice
);

-- Insert values into the table.
INSERT INTO dbo.Products (QtyAvailable, UnitPrice)
VALUES (25, 2.00), (10, 1.5);

-- Display the rows in the table.
SELECT ProductID, QtyAvailable, UnitPrice, InventoryValue
FROM dbo.Products;
```

In your case you can find `CHARINDEX` of `.` in `Object Path` and do a substring to populate `File Type`

Here are some links to help this:

[Computed Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx)

[CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

[SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Cheers !!